# Remote desktop connection terminated

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've very odd problem. The server os is windows server 2008 r2. When I want to connect to it by remote desktop, after click on connect, it keep get back to RDP client each time again. without showing any error or anything else!! I've a control panel that have access to restart/stop any service, if it helps.

any help/suggestion really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is normally happens when on the target server where it's on a state that does not allow RDP such as it's shutting down or coming up and installing patches before shutting down or coming up. or also after installing roles or features that require system reboot.

post back with what you find, and we'll see what else to look for to get this issue resolved.